# Joining 2 result

Tags: jquery, join, checkbox, alert, concatenation

I have a button that does the following to rows that are checked. I added .join('') to remove a comma that will appear from 2nd return value onwards

```
var getName = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
return ($(this).parent().next().next().next().next().next().next().text());
}).get().join('');

var getNum = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
return ($(this).parent().next().next().next().next().text());
}).get()join('');

alert(getName.concat(getNum));
```

The output is as follows when i checked 3 rows and clicked the button:

Name1
Name2
Name3
Num1

Num2

Num3

---

When i stringify the return elements:

```
var getName = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
return JSON.stringify($(this).parent().next().next().next().next().next().next().text());
}).get().join('');

var getNum = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
return JSON.stringify($(this).parent().next().next().next().next().text());
}).get()join('');

alert(getName.concat(getNum));
```

The output is as follows:

"\n Name1""\n Name2""\n Name3""\n Num1\n ""\n Num2\n ""\n Num3\n "

---

How can i get the output to be like this?

Name1 Num 1
Name3 Num 2
Name3 Num 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try join the two map call to one, like this:

```
var getName = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
return $(this).parent().next().next().next().next().next().next().text()
    + ' ' + $(this).parent().next().next().next().next().text();
}).get().join('');

alert(getName);
```

by the way, why are you using so much "next()", what about mark the target DOM element with a "id" or "class" attributes?? Cause now it looks a little scary >_<|||

Hope this can help

Comment: Thanks. it works. Now it shows Name1</n>Num1</n>Name2</n>Num2. Any idea how to remove </n> between Name & Num?

Comment: So if I name the first id as gName and the 2nd as gNum how do I mark the target DOM element?

Comment: 1. remove the "</n>" use the "replace"function, eg: `$(this).parent().text().replace('</n>', '')`, 2. select the DOM element use id selector, like "#id", in your case, you want select the sibling after '$(this).parent()' whose id attributes is 'gName', try `$(this).parent().nextUntil('#gName')`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Cheers!

Comment: glad to hear that, best wish! ^_^